# Google adsense not showing any ad with no error in the console

Tags: javascript, iframe, localhost, adsense

10 hours back I created a responsive ad unit with Google AdSense. 
When I paste their JavaScript code in my html I got a `400 error`, I looked for the error and found that I happens if a recently created ad unit is deployed on a webpage. So I waited.

After 1 hour the 400 error was gone and no errors in the console.

But I couldn't see any ad on my webpage.

I created a div with width `342px` with 3px padding from right and left. Hence the ad size should be `336` which is a valid ad size.

I am able to see a box, and the iframe contains this:

```
<iframe id="google_ads_frame1" name="google_ads_frame1" width="336" height="280" frameborder="0" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-4113014063873003&amp;format=336x280&amp;output=html&amp;h=280&amp;slotname=5729326026&amp;adk=3501074280&amp;adf=503411769&amp;w=336&amp;lmt=1504241513&amp;loeid=368226015&amp;rafmt=1&amp;flash=0&amp;fwr=0&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fawesome-images%2Fpublic%2Fhome&amp;resp_fmts=3&amp;wgl=1&amp;dt=1504241512729&amp;bpp=188&amp;bdt=472&amp;fdt=201&amp;idt=265&amp;shv=r20170828&amp;cbv=r20170110&amp;saldr=aa&amp;correlator=7612069580798&amp;frm=20&amp;ga_vid=1421514613.1504241513&amp;ga_sid=1504241513&amp;ga_hid=1290139134&amp;ga_fc=0&amp;pv=2&amp;iag=3&amp;icsg=2&amp;nhd=1&amp;dssz=2&amp;mdo=0&amp;mso=0&amp;u_tz=330&amp;u_his=1&amp;u_java=0&amp;u_h=768&amp;u_w=1366&amp;u_ah=728&amp;u_aw=1366&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_nplug=4&amp;u_nmime=5&amp;adx=38&amp;ady=389&amp;biw=1349&amp;bih=446&amp;abxe=1&amp;eid=368226005%2C575144605%2C21060849&amp;oid=3&amp;ref=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fawesome-images%2Fpublic%2Fadmin%2Fgoogleads&amp;rx=0&amp;eae=0&amp;fc=528&amp;brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1366%2C0%2C1366%2C728%2C1366%2C446&amp;vis=1&amp;rsz=do%7C%7CeE%7C&amp;abl=CS&amp;ppjl=u&amp;pfx=0&amp;fu=144&amp;bc=1&amp;ifi=1&amp;xpc=9bIU6SPwBy&amp;p=http%3A//127.0.0.1&amp;dtd=352" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

<iframe id="google_osd_static_frame_2450693750800" name="google_osd_static_frame" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

Is there any problem with my end? or Google takes more time to display a newly created ad unit?
I am on **localhost** for testing. Is it because of that??

Note: I have previoisly created many ad units and they all were working fine with my online websites.